# Referring own class in C# with VS2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

This might be a stupid question, but…

I am moving towards Visual Studio Community 2022 (version 17.3.3, just in case).

I create a C# console application, using the .NET 6.0 Framework, and create a new class ‘Foo’ by right-clicking the project and selecting Add -> Class. The IDE generates an internal class
Foo (let us leave it empty for simplicity).
I then add in the Program.cs file a declaration of an object of my new class, like:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Foo F = new Foo();
```

The issue is that this simple code generates a CS0246 compile error (“Foo not found”).

Of course, I can add a using directive at the beginning of Program.cs, but:

- As a teacher in charge of an introductory programming class, I like to start from the basics: this forces me to introduce using directives even before giving an intuition of what a class is. I know .NET has not been designed for teaching purposes, yet…
- From what I read, VS 2022 wanted to improve productivity, by avoiding the need to have 10 lines of code before being able to perform the slightest action, and moving to something closer to Python instead. How is this goal helped by not including the project’s own namespace in the default using directives ?!?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is `Foo` and `Program` in the same namespace? If not, rename the namespace where `Foo` is declared to match that of the one `Program` is declared in. Better yet just place the code for the declaration of `Foo` just above the `class Program { }`  declaration. PS for local variables and fields use lowercase letters, as in `Foo f = new Foo();`

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is that you don't need to put your `Foo` class in a namespace.

In your "Foo.cs" file you can put just this (note the lack of a namespace):

```
class Foo
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Then in your "Program.cs" you can put this, and it will compile OK:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

It's bad practice to not use a namespace, but that can be for a later lesson.

Comment: Of course, adding the class with the 'Add' context menu, the namespace is auto-generated. It can be removed but having beginner students remove it without an explanation is perhaps not optimal from a didactic point of view...

Comment: @JohanDonne You could just make sure that they are both in the same namespace, and then you wouldn't need to add a `using` either - you'd just need `namespace Whatever;` in both files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, but not unexpectedly, it doesn't really solve my problem. I can of course remove the namespace, or add a using directive, but, as some comments pointed out, this is still some strange manipulation for starter students.

I must say I am still confused by this Microsoft decision:
- Why does the standard way of creating a new class require extra steps to work?
- Why is the "new flavor" of Main put outside the application namespace?

... but I suppose I would need to ask Microsoft for this.